# Calculate Mode and Median for data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I have a table facility that holds a score for each day (Multiple scores can be reported each day and both would be valid)

I need to calculate the Mode and Median score by month.

Facility:

```
Id   Month Date  score
1    Jan     1    5
1    Jan     1    5
1    Jan     2    3
1    Jan     3    4
1    Jan     4    4
1    Jan     5    4
1    Feb     1    5
1    Feb     1    5
1    Feb     2    3
1    Feb     3    4
1    Feb     4    4
1    Feb     5    4
```

Is there any way to do it through SQL?right now my option is to export the complete data-set and do it using excel

Thanks for your help.

Comment: mode is easy enough. calculate total rows in a group, then get whatever rows are around #rows/2.

Comment: @MarcB..mode is the number that appears the most number of times in a group. i thought you meant median.